# Count Occurrence of Value in Loop

Tags: json, vb.net

I am reading a Json Array that returns Dates.

What I want to do is loop through the Json array, store the dates occurred, and count how many times each date occurred.

```
       Using client As New WebClient
            Dim feedResponse As String = client.DownloadString(Url)
            Dim jsonObject As Object = JSONHelper.Deserialize(feedResponse)
            Dim feedArray As JArray = JSONHelper.readJSonArray(jsonObject, "data")

                For i = 0 To feedArray.Count - 1
                    Dim feedDetailsObject As Object = feedArray.ElementAt(i)
                    Dim feeddate = JSONHelper.readJSonElement(feedDetailsObject, "updated_time").ToShortDateString
                Next

            End If
        End Using
```

I want to count how many times "feeddate" value occurs.

What is the best way to count occurrence of same value in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy` to count number of occurrence of each `updated_time` value :

```
Dim groupedDates = feedArray.GroupBy(Function(x) JSONHelper.readJSonElement(x, "updated_time").ToShortDateString)
For Each group In groupedDates
    Dim feedDate = group.Key
    Dim numberOfOccurrence = group.Count()
Next
```

Comment: This is returning the first date that it gets in the loop., and giving it the count of total dates...